# How to make sources enter the assembly line based on the timings in a schedule in simulating a discrete-event system in AnyLogic software?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate a discrete event system with the following specifications in AnyLogic software:
This system comprises 3 assembly station, to simulate each of which we use "service" block. I have drawn also an agent named "order" into the main. We have 6 different products, and the time on which they need to enter the assembly line are stored in a data base. The data base has 4 columns: row number, product id, order time, and due date. My questions are as follows:

1. Do I need 6 different sources attached to service 1, in the beginning of the line, or just 1 source?
2. Do I need a java code to make each product enter the line based on the time table? or I can do so using the blocks in AnyLogic?
3. I want to calculate the lateness of delivery for each product. I need to store the delivery time of each product in a variable and compare it with the its corresponding due date in the data base.

I would sincerely appreciate your helps.

I have tried using the "Set agent parameters from DB" option but it did not work.

Comment: And only use the "anylogic" tag, else other people will get confused here on SOF :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need 6 different sources attached to service 1, in the beginning of the line, or just 1 source?

Your choice, both are possible and have advantages and disadvantages. 1 source is easier to model but requires more AnyLogic experience.

> Do I need a java code to make each product enter the line based on the time table? or I can do so using the blocks in AnyLogic?

See the step-by-step tutorials and example models, there show you how to load and create agents from data.

> I want to calculate the lateness of delivery for each product. I need to store the delivery time of each product in a variable and compare it with the its corresponding due date in the data base.

No question here. But you are right. This is what you need to do... :)